# How to compare two column and return the largest one as a new column in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Here is what I've tried:

```
SELECT
  cln.CLNID,
  MAX(cln.lastinputdate) clnlast ,
  MAX(subac.lastinputdate) sublast , 
  (CASE
      WHEN clnlast > sublast   
  THEN clnlast
      ELSE sublast 
  END) as lasttime
FROM
  IBROKER.cln cln
LEFT JOIN IBROKER.ClnSrvSubAc subac
ON
  cln.clnid=subac.clnid
GROUP BY
  cln.clnid,
```

But it ends up with a error "ORA-00904: "CLNLAST": invalid identifier"

Please help.

Comment: `greatest(max(col1), max(col2))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't reference an alias defined in your `select` list elsewhere in the `select` list.  You'd need to use the actual column names.  You also don't need to use a `case` here-- Oracle provides a `greatest` function

```
 greatest( max( cln.lastinputdate ), max( subac.lastinputdate ) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use column alias in this case. I think it should be:

```
SELECT
  cln.CLNID,
  MAX(cln.lastinputdate) clnlast ,
  MAX(subac.lastinputdate) sublast , 
  (CASE
      WHEN MAX(cln.lastinputdate)> MAX(subac.lastinputdate)
  THEN MAX(cln.lastinputdate)
      ELSE MAX(subac.lastinputdate)
  END) as lasttime
FROM
  IBROKER.cln cln
LEFT JOIN IBROKER.ClnSrvSubAc subac
ON
  cln.clnid=subac.clnid
GROUP BY
  cln.clnid;
```